# Invoke-Command with remote session: Cannot validate argument on parameter

Tags: powershell, remote-access

I wrote a script to restart a few ASP.NET websites on a remote server:

```bsh
$computerName = #...
$password = #...
$secureStringPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -String $password
$userName = #...
$credential= New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($userName, $secureStringPassword)
$websiteNames = #..., #..., #...

Get-PSSession -ComputerName $computerName -Credential $credential | Remove-PSSession 

$psSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $computerName -Credential $credential

Invoke-Command -Session $psSession -ScriptBlock { $websiteNames | foreach{ Stop-Website -Name $_ } }
Invoke-Command -Session $psSession -ScriptBlock { $websiteNames | foreach{ Start-Website -Name $_ } }

$psSession | Remove-PSSession
```

For some reasons my `Invoke-Command` do not run properly, I have the following error message:

> Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Name'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again.

When the commands are run after an `Enter-PSSession` it works fine within a `-ScriptBlock` it kinda mess up the `-Name` parameter, any idea how to fix that up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The remote session cannot access the variables you have defined locally. They can be referenced with `$using:variable`

```
Invoke-Command -Session $psSession -ScriptBlock { $using:websiteNames | foreach{ Stop-Website -Name $_ } }
Invoke-Command -Session $psSession -ScriptBlock { $using:websiteNames | foreach{ Start-Website -Name $_ } }
```

More information in the `about_remote_variables` help:

```
get-help about_remote_variables -Full
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually just needed to pass the arguments to the `-ArgumentList` of the `-ScriptBlock` and use `$args` to reference to it within the function block:

```bsh
Invoke-Command -Session $psSession -ScriptBlock { $args | foreach{ Stop-Website -Name $_ } } -ArgumentList $websiteNames
Invoke-Command -Session $psSession -ScriptBlock { $args | foreach{ Start-Website -Name $_ } } -ArgumentList $websiteNames
```